# Transpose method for finding a basis for the row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, soft-question, transpose

My linear algebra textbook outlines a method of finding a basis for the row space of a matrix by finding a basis for the column space of its transpose. Is there any point of using this method? It seems to me like it's adding another step (finding the transpose) for no apparent increase in simplicity.

Comment: It means you can do row reduction and so fits in neatly to what you already know

Comment: @Paul But I can also do row reduction on the original matrix, why bother doing it on the transpose instead?

Comment: Just for consistency. In practice, there is no benefit to this, but from a theoretical perspective, you don't have to prove the validity of your methods twice.

Comment: Why do we not teach column-reduction? ...

Answer (score 0):

Both methods let you find a basis for the row space. The difference is that row-reducing the transpose lets you pick out a set of the *original* rows that form a basis, while row-reducing the original matrix gives you a “nice” basis in that the first few elements (up to the rank of the matrix) of each vector consist of a single $1$ and otherwise zeros.